# Aggregate by factor or character?

Tags: r, aggregate

How do you use aggregate if your unique column ID is a character?

```
aggregate(data, list(data$colID), sum)
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

Change to character..

```
data$colID<-as.character(data$colID)

aggregate(data, list(data$colID), sum)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

ddply I get a similar error.  
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

I only want to aggregate by the colID, I dont want to sum it.  I want all the other columns to sum.

```
dput(data)
structure(list(colID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), col1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2), col2 = c(0, 
1, 0, 2, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), col4 = c(5, 5, 5, 7, 7)), .Names = c("colID", 
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
aggregate(x = DF[, -1], by = list(DF$colID), FUN = "sum")
```

Where DF is your data.frame

Using `ddply` from `plyr` package

```
ddply(DF, .(colID), numcolwise(sum))

   colID col1 col2 col3 col4
1     a    1    1    1   15
2     b    2    2    0   14
```

usign either `acast` or `dcast`  from `reshape2` package

```
acast( melt(DF), variable ~ colID, sum)  # a matrix
dcast( melt(DF), variable ~ colID, sum)  # a data.frame

Using colID as id variables
      a  b
col1  1  2
col2  1  2
col3  1  0
col4 15 14
```

**EDIT**
Using `ddply`. Not so elegant, but it works!

```
 Sums <- ddply(DF[, -5], .(colID), numcolwise(sum))
 Mean <- ddply(DF[, c(1,5)], .(colID), numcolwise(mean))[,-1]
 cbind(Sums, col4_mean=Mean)
  colID col1 col2 col3 col4_mean
1     a    1    1    1         5
2     b    2    2    0         7
```

Comment: ok.  Using the ddply function is nicer.  What if I wanted to sum col1, col2, col3 but mean for col4?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `data.table` solution. It will not matter whether the by column is factor or character.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(data)
# Calculates the sum of columns col1, ..., col3
# and mean of col4
merge(DT[, lapply(.SD, sum),by = colID, .SDcols =paste0('col', 1:3)], 
      DT[, lapply(.SD, mean),by = colID, .SDcols ='col4'], 
  by = 'colID')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(reshape2)
melted_data <- melt(df, id.vars = "colID")
dcast(melted_data, colID ~ variable, sum)
```